# JSON object compression while sending push notification ios/android using php

Tags: php, android, ios, json, compression

I am sending the push notifications in the chat module using curl for IOS and FCM for android. In which we are sending some of our database entities to enable users to share our in-app content with each other.

**Scenario:**

As a third party, I am using **pusher** to deliver messages on the channels. I am sending push notifications to those users who are not connected to the **pusher** channel but still present on the application i.e application in the background.

**Problem:**

My push notifications are working fine with text messages, but when adding my database entity in the notification its size grows dramatically. Of course, I know when whenever I add more data the size will obviously grow. But It is the requirement from our mobile team to send a complete payload on push notification as they updating their local database on push notification trigger.
When the size of the payload exceeds **1.8kb** the mobile applications especially the **IOS** party is not able to receive the trigger as well as data.

**Question:**

My question is, is there any technique to compress string data on the server end and decompress it mobile application end. I am also attaching JSON size analysis with this question.

I have also looked into different hashing and encryption algorithms like sha1 etc. But they are only one encryption techniques.

P.S: My programming language is PHP and I am using **Laravel** as a framework.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as iOS is concerned, a push notification can trigger the launch of an **UNNotificationServiceExtension**, which is a mini-app that can process the notification's data whenever a notification is received, even if the app itself is not running. The iOS developers can use this window in order to uncompress your data. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension
There are a lot of 3rd party libraries that can be used in Swift / Objective C for uncompressing standard formats (such as gzip)

Comment: I am actually looking for a compression technique on the server end, that could also work fine on the mobile applications so that data could be approriate.